# QuickBooks API v3 - support for Payment with DetailType of AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail

Tags: api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

In IPP v2, I use the Check entity extensively, often with account-based lines (and sometimes with Item-based lines).  I use it both to write checks to QuickBooks and to read checks from QuickBooks.

I had thought that the IPP v3 equivalent was the Payment entity, with lines having DetailType of AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail or ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail.

However, the IPP v3 docs for Payment (https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/payment) say that for the Line element in Payment, QBD only supports PaymentLineDetail and DiscountLineDetail (no mention of AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail).

Is it correct to believe that a Payment with Lines of type AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail or ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail is indeed the equivalent of an IPP v2 Check?  And, are the docs correct to say that these particular LineDetailTypeEnum types are not yet supported in the IPP v3 Payment entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payment entity in v3 is not equivalent to checks in v2. 
There is a Purchase entity in v3 which supports Cash, Check, and Credit Card.
It has the ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail, AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail, (QBD)GroupLineDetail.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/purchase

I think this is what you are looking for.